# Defining relations of SU(2) and SU(4)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Defining relations are relations among the generators of a group, $\{g_a\}$, such that $\prod g_a^{n_a}=e$, where $e$ is the identity element. The multiplication rule of a group can always be specified by a set of defining relations.

For $SU(2)$ and $SU(4)$, what are the sets of defining relations that completely specify their multiplication rules? Do they depend on the representations?

Comment: You certainly can always specify the multiplication of a group by the set of relations of the form $g_1 g_2 g_3 = e$, where $g_1$ and $g_2$ run through all the elements of the group and $g_3 = g_2^{-1} g_1^{-1}$. I suspect they want you to find a smaller set of generators and relations, though...

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes, I am asking the smallest possible set of defining relations that completely specifies the multiplication rule

Comment: Are you given a set of generators? It very much depends on what generators you choose.

Comment: You need uncountably many generators to generate all of the group, just by cardinality considerations. That's one of the reasons why it is useful to study the group through its Lie algebra instead of directly through generators and relations, since the Lie algebra is finitely generated.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Suppose we are using fundamental representation, where for $SU(2)$ we use Pauli matrices and for $SU(4)$ we use the 15 generators defined as follows: 5 of them, $\Gamma_a$, satisfy $\Gamma_a\Gamma_b+\Gamma_b\Gamma_a=2\delta_{ab}I$ and the other 10 are constructed as $\Gamma_{ab}=\frac{1}{2i}(\Gamma_a\Gamma_b-\Gamma_b\Gamma_a)$, then these 15 matrices are the generators of $SU(4)$ in the fundamental representation

Comment: As @HenningMakholm indicated, you seem to think of this on the level of Lie algebras, not as an abstract group. I think you need to rephrase the question to make clear what exactly you are asking.